# Is there a shorter way to find length of an array than this C code?

Tags: c, code-analysis, compression

```
static int a[] = {1, 5, 645, 43, 4, 65, 5408, 4, 7, 90, 23, 11};
int len=sizeof(a)/sizeof(int);
```

Is there a shortcut, with ANSI 99?

Comment: A good question. I seem in C - no.

Comment: (except for VLAs) `sizeof arr / sizeof *arr` is a compile time constant. Why do you want a different way? *Try a macro*

Comment: Why not `size_t`? Are you hoping someday to have negative `len`? :)

Comment: @pmg: nah, surely it's in hope of provoking UB on a 64 bit system. For a really big array.

Comment: UB means Unexpected Behavior?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that there isn't a shortcut, but you cat use macro:

```
#define arrlen(arr) (sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]))
```

Comment: +1, but I'd probably write it all uppercase, to make it evident that it's a macro.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a shorter way to find length of an array than this C code?

Yes, one character shorter:

```
static int a[] = {1, 5, 645, 43, 4, 65, 5408, 4, 7, 90, 23, 11};
int len=sizeof a/sizeof(int);
```

**edit:** There's an even shorter version suggested by @pmg:

```
static int a[] = {1, 5, 645, 43, 4, 65, 5408, 4, 7, 90, 23, 11};
int len=sizeof a/sizeof*a;
```

You could also use fewer characters for the identifier `len`.

:)

Comment: hehe: `sizeof a/sizeof*a`: 3 chars less than your version.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the number of *elements* in the array,

```
sizeof arr / sizeof *arr
```

or

```
sizeof arr / sizeof arr[0]
```

are about as short as it gets.  Just remember that unless `arr` is a VLA, these will be computed at compile time.

Also remember that this only works if `arr` is an *array* expression, not a pointer. If you do something like

```
void foo(int arr[])
{
   size_t len = sizeof arr / sizeof *arr;
   ...
}
```

you won't get the answer you expect, because in this context `arr` is a *pointer* expression, not an array (refer to the online [C language standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf), § 6.3.2.1 ¶ 3 and § 6.5.7.3 ¶ 7).